# How to send React hook's setter to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have this kind of hook:-

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
displayName: '',
realName: '',
birthDate: '',
height: 0,
cityLocation: '',
occupation: '',
ethnicity: ''
}
```

Later in the code, I am passing it as props to a class component as:-

```
  <SelectEthnicity 
  data={{profile:profile,
    setProfile: {setProfile}}} 
   />
```

SelectEthnicity is a class component. It's just a wrapper of select. This select has many options. Here is the little code snippet.

```
export class SelectEthnicity extends Component {
render() {
    console.warn("this.props.data.setProfile", this.props.data.setProfile)
    return (
            <select value={this.props.data.profile.ethnicity} // this is fine.
             // TypeError: this.props.data.setProfile is not a function
            onChange={(input) => {this.props.data.setProfile({ ...this.props.data.profile, [input.target.name]: input.target.value })}}
            name="ethnicity" ref={this.props.form.register}>
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>
                <option value="southAsian">South Asian</option>
                <option value="southEastAsian">South East Asian</option>
                <option value="mixed">Mixed</option>
```

I got an error as:

> TypeError: this.props.data.setProfile is not a function

So porps is not passing setProfile as a function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, setProfile is an object containing a setProfile function.

You just need to remove the curly braces around it.

```
<SelectEthnicity 
  data={{
    profile: profile,
    setProfile: setProfile
  }} 
/>
```

Or:

```
<SelectEthnicity data={{ profile, setProfile }} />
```